# Greenplum error requested WAL segment has already been removed

Tags: greenplum

I have a Greenplum cluster.I am monitoring it through GPmon 
I am getting error 
**requested WAL segment 00000001000000080000000F has already been removed**. 
How to remove this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the standby master and then reinitializing it to resolve this issue.

Thanks!